# Spring Boot - Select service implemenation via command line

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to select what service implementation to use via a command line option or value in the application.properties files (ideally with a default). Does that solution works with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

My use case is the following: I have an application that has 3 service implementations, and depending on the environment I would like to select one or the other.

Currently only one of the implementations is marked with `@Service`, as otherwise `@EnableAutoConfiguration` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Spring profiles](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/). Mark each `@Bean` implementation with `@Profile("...")` and then start your app with `spring.profiles.active=...` to select the beans you need.

Comment: that  works. However I had to introduce some duplication in my configuration and integration tests. Both in the main of my configuration and my IntegrationTest I had to put System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "both");, where "both" is the default profile. Any suggestions to define the default profile only once?

Comment: I wouldn't use System properties (what if there's another app running in the same JVM?). You can use `@ActiveProfile` in the tests and `SpringApplication` (or the builder) to set profiles in the main method. Or you can put it in `application.properties` if it's really a global setting.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. I changed the configuration both in the tests and in the config. But I still don;t like the fact that the default is replicated both in the application configuration and in my unit test. Do you now if there is a way to somehow inherit the default?